# Plotting two columns of dataFrame in seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to create a bar chart in seaborn that displays values for two variables(Weight, Variance) for each row (Factor) in my data frame. Here is what my data looks like:

```
    Factor    Weight  Variance
    Growth    10%      0.15
    Value     20%      0.35
```

Here is my code:

```
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax1=fig.add_subplot(221)
    sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df[['Weight', 'Variance']], ax=ax1)
```

The above throws back an error every time that I can't debug. What I am trying to achieve is have one plot, that shows two colored bars for each Factor; weight in one color (ex: red) and variance in another color (ex: blue).

Anyone have suggestions or potential workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Aside from cleaning up your data into a tidy format, you need to reformat the text data (percentages) into numeric data types. Since that has nothing to do with barplots, I'll assume you can take care of that on your own and focus on the plotting and data structures instead:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Factor': ['Growth', 'Value'],
    'Weight': [0.10, 0.20],
    'Variance': [0.15, 0.35]
})
fig, ax1 = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
tidy = df.melt(id_vars='Factor').rename(columns=str.title)
seaborn.barplot(x='Factor', y='Value', hue='Variable', data=tidy, ax=ax1)
seaborn.despine(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: `tidy = df.melt(id_vars='Factor').rename(columns=str.title)` Can you please explain this part of your code? what does it mean `columns = str.title`?

Comment: @mr.sanatbek [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) is a built-in python method to capitalize strings, e.g. `'abc'.title()` returns `'Abc'`. [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) accepts not only dicts (map keys to values) but also functions (apply function to all elements), so `df.rename(columns=str.title)` applies `str.title` to all column names, i.e. capitalizes them.